# how to know when a app is opened by homebutton longpress in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I had a small problem
1.In my app I have both widget and application.
2.If a person uses the widget he will enter into the gallery and ask him to select the image whenever he select the image it will placed as wallpaper.
3.where as in app he will have different choices to use(ex:customizing..etc)
4.So whenever the person used widget and longpress on home screen and selected the app it was opening gallery which is used for widget.
5.But according to my requirement whenever he long press on home screen and selected the app it should go to main application but not widget's one....
Im stugling this...is there any solution for this...hope i have given clear description...if u dont understand plzz let me know

Comment: I'm not sure how widgets work, but I guess it should call the app through a Intent. In that case maybe you can add an extra parameter in the intent to know in "onResume" where the focus comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the homebutton puts the app in paused state you can perform the operations by overriding onPause method.

whenever he long press on home screen and selected the app it resumes from the paused state 
you can define any action when app resumes in onResume method.

Comment: it was calling from oncreate method

Comment: onResume will be called anyways

Comment: so the another problem raised here is if open the widget at first also it ws calling onresume method so it was not making me to complete the widget task

Comment: set a boolean isFirst set it to true 1st time and set it to false in onPause method

Answer (score 0):

This is as designed by Android,. Long press of home shows you recent apps with saved state. 
so since the user has used widget and then long presses to select app. it will show last saved state that is widget gallery.

Comment: From what i can think of, you could create widget and app seperately.